# How to deploy/run a Docker image from a build server

Tags: docker, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity

Having built,run and executed tests against a docker image on a CI build server(TeamCity2017), how should we deploy it to further machines?

How, for example, if we push it to a Docker registry, would our CI server instruct the target machine to pull and run the image? I.e. where it an application we would use Octopus for this deployment step, but our Octopus server doesn't support Docker deployments as yet.

Any guidance appreciated.

Michael McD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Octo to deploy your images onto target machines. You'd need to use powershell scripts to have your machines run the images. Or you can use something like Rancher, which is a docker swarm manager. There is no feasible way to have TeamCity deploy your images. The software simply isn't built to be able to do deploys.

The Rancher solution would not be automated, at least not to my knowledge. You would have to trigger upgrades when a new image is pushed to the docker registry.

Comment: Hi, I think  that confirms our thoughts.  We're going with the Octopus  solution, as Octopus has a Docker registry we can get TC to push to  that and have Octopus  deploy those images to appropriate targets.  Then as you suggest start up containers using PS (unless Octopus has an available build step).